# Undoing my mistake using git reset --hard

Tags: git, version-control

I accidentally added some files using `git add .` . I would like to remove the changes using `git reset --hard`. When I type so, I get this error message.

```
fatal: Failed to resolve 'HEAD' as a valid ref
```

I tried typing `git reset --hard HEAD^`. Still not able to solve it.

How do I solve it?

Comment: and what say git reset path/to/file  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to construct the initial commit in a newly created repo.

Since you haven't actually committed anything yet, you can just start over by removing the `.git` directory and running `git init` again.

---

Alternatively, you can try `git rm --cached .` to remove the files from the index.

Comment: how do u remove the .git directory? in my folder, there is only gitignore file which i created.

Comment: @lakesh a simple `rm -Rf .git/` will do. this is an OS operation, not a git command.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `git reset origin/master`?

or change `origin/master` to a commit id if you have some not pushed commits you would like to keep.